# Harmon.ie sidebar and ribbon is missing

Tags: outlook, harmon.ie

One of my users has suddenly lost the Outlook sidebar and the harmon.ie ribbon band is replaced with another icon with the words "Save to Sharepoint" but it is deactivated (grey). Also there is no arrow to see options and no other choices available. We tried to uninstall and reinstall. Nothing changes. How do we get back the Outlook sidebar?
/Susannevj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-In order to rule out any plugin conflict would you please check whether any additional plugins are enabled in Outlook - if so, disable (temporarily) all other add-ins except harmon.ie To disable Outlook add-ins
•   Go under File -> Options -> Add-ins -> Manage COM Add-ins and click Go...
•   Deselect all add-ins except harmon.ie and click OK.

Restart Outlook - and go back under File -> Options -> Add-ins to verify that harmon.ie is the only add-in listed in the Active application add-ins section.
 Then please run the following recovery procedure:

-Please stop Outlook.

-Uninstall harmon.ie from control panel, program feature

-Delete all dirs.  C:\Users[user_name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\harmony_Path_pzllr20oqrnqmrstb3lfbn4njpshdzry (path can slightly change)

-Delete C:\Users[user_name]\AppData\Local\Mainsoft

-Register the registry key at: ftp://free:free@ftpus.mainsoft.com/Clean%20Mainsoft%20Reg_New.reg.zip

-Register the PreferredCLRversion registry key at ftp://free:free@ftpus.mainsoft.com/PreferredCLRVersion4.0.zip

-Reinstall latest harmon.ie version from the below link
ftp://free:free@ftpus.mainsoft.com/HarmonieSharePointSetup.x86.msi

-Start Outlook